# In Mxgrapg custom icon how can I add title for custom Icons?

Tags: javascript, html, mxgraph

Using Mxgraph I am creating a tool where I have only Custom icons.

I need to add names under custom Icon in toolbox and also while icon drag and drop the name also should come below the icon in the container.
Here is the below code you can use for reference

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        mxBasePath = 'src';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/mxClient.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function main()
        {

                var tbContainer = document.getElementById('tbContainer');
                var toolbar = new mxToolbar(tbContainer);
                toolbar.enabled = false

                container = document.getElementById('container');

                if (mxClient.IS_QUIRKS)
                {
                    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
                    new mxDivResizer(tbContainer);
                    new mxDivResizer(container);
                }
                var model = new mxGraphModel();
                var graph = new mxGraph(container, model);
                graph.dropEnabled = true;

                var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
            var style = new Object();
            style[mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE] = mxConstants.SHAPE_IMAGE;
            style[mxConstants.STYLE_PERIMETER] = mxPerimeter.RectanglePerimeter;
            style[mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE] = 'images/svg/start.svg';
            style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTCOLOR] = '#FFFFFF';
            graph.getStylesheet().putCellStyle('imagestart', style);

                mxDragSource.prototype.getDropTarget = function(graph, x, y)
                {
                    var cell = graph.getCellAt(x, y);

                    if (!graph.isValidDropTarget(cell))
                    {
                        cell = null;
                    }                       
                    return cell;
                };
                graph.setConnectable(true);
                graph.setMultigraph(false);

                var keyHandler = new mxKeyHandler(graph);
                var rubberband = new mxRubberband(graph);

                var addVertex = function(icon, w, h, style)
                {
                    var vertex = new mxCell(null, new mxGeometry(0, 0, w, h), style);
                    vertex.setVertex(true);
                    //vertex.setText("Icon name");
                    addToolbarItem(graph, toolbar, vertex, icon);
                };
                toolbar.addLine();
                addVertex('images/rectangle.gif', 100, 40, '');             
                addVertex('images/sample.png', 50, 50, 'imagestart');               
                toolbar.addLine();
        }

        function addToolbarItem(graph, toolbar, prototype, image)
        {
            var funct = function(graph, evt, cell)
            {
                graph.stopEditing(false);
                var pt = graph.getPointForEvent(evt);
                var vertex = graph.getModel().cloneCell(prototype);
                vertex.geometry.x = pt.x;
                vertex.geometry.y = pt.y;
                graph.setSelectionCells(graph.importCells([vertex], 0, 0, cell));
            }
            var img = toolbar.addMode(null, image, funct);
            mxUtils.makeDraggable(img, graph, funct);

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="main()">
 <div id="container" style="position:absolute;overflow:hidden;left:0px;top:26px;right:150px;bottom:0px;background:url('src/images/grid.gif');"></div>
<div id="tbContainer" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden;padding:2px; left:1400px;top:26px; width:24px; bottom:0px;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Here I have added an image where I have added red mark. I need to add text in that place.

```
vertex.setText("Icon name");
```

Help me to figure out this issues

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. This may be useful for some others.

Its very simple.

while addToolbarItem we just need to specify the name of the tool icon like this

```
var img = toolbar.addMode("Start", image, funct);
```

and on drag and drop we need to pass the text like below

```
var vertex = new mxCell("start", new mxGeometry(0, 0, w, h), style);
```

For giving style for the text you can add the style like the below

```
style[mxConstants.STYLE_VERTICAL_LABEL_POSITION] = 'top';
                     style[mxConstants.STYLE_VERTICAL_ALIGN] = 'bottom';
                     style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTSIZE] = '18';
                     //style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTSTYLE] = 1;
                     style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTCOLOR] = '#333';
                     style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTFAMILY] = 'Lato-Regular';
                     style['fontWeight'] = 'regular';
            graph.getStylesheet().putCellStyle('imagestart', style);
```

With spending few hours I got this solutions. Please correct me if I am doing any wrong

Comment: not sure i understand your solution.where is image coming from in var img. also is image the string path to the image?

Comment: How do i add a text under a toolbar icon?